# Anybody help me about video content on website, it made heavy to my website?

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, html5-video, pagespeed

I uploaded a video on website and its 10mb video. It increase my Homepage Size from 4mb to 14mb. Anybody have better solution to upload a video on a website, and it makes much better my website speed. before uploading video my website speed was 52 and now it is only 27.

Comment: If you use AJAX or another means to asynchronous load content. You can let the video load while the website runs. When the video is done loading it would be displayed.

Comment: i hope it will work for video speed but how about the page size...

Comment: You just need to lazy load the video
Or prevent the player from autoplaying it
Or better, upload it to youtube for example and use and emedded video

Comment: but youtube will increase http request on my website and it will also increase the loading time

Comment: Or you may just host yoru video elsewhere and link to it from your website.

Comment: "_my website speed was 52 and now it is only 27_" how did you get those numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent your player from loading the video automatically or use a better solution:
You can upload the video to youtube, and then lazy load it in your website (it will cost only one request: the video thumbnail)
Here is the method I'm using to lazy load my youtube videos:

```js
(function($){

 var youtube = document.querySelectorAll( ".youtubez" );
 
 for (var i = 0; i < youtube.length; i++) {
  youtube[i].addEventListener( "click", function() {

   var iframe = document.createElement( "iframe" );

     iframe.setAttribute( "frameborder", "0" );
     iframe.setAttribute( "allowfullscreen", "" );
     iframe.setAttribute( "src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+ this.dataset.embed +"?rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1" );

     this.innerHTML = "";
     this.appendChild( iframe );
  } ); 
 };

})(jQuery);
```

```css
/* Lazy load youtube videos */
.youtubez{background-color:#000;margin-top:8px;position:relative;padding-top:56.25%;overflow:hidden;cursor:pointer}
.youtubez img{width:100%;top:-16.82%;left:0;opacity:.7}
.youtubez .play-button{width:90px;height:60px;background-color:#333;box-shadow:0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);z-index:1;opacity:.8;border-radius:6px}
.youtubez .play-button:before{content:"";border-style:solid;border-width:15px 0 15px 26px;border-color:transparent transparent transparent #fff}
.youtubez img,.youtubez .play-button{cursor:pointer}
.youtubez img,.youtubez iframe,.youtubez .play-button,.youtubez .play-button:before{position:absolute}
.youtubez .play-button,.youtubez .play-button:before{top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate3d(-50%,-50%,0)}
.youtubez iframe{height:100%;width:100%;top:0;left:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="youtubez" data-embed="jNQXAC9IVRw"><div class="play-button">&nbsp;</div><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/jNQXAC9IVRw/0.jpg"></div>
```

I don't know why the example doesn't work in stackoverflow (maybe for security reasons preventing iframes) but here is a working jsbin http://jsbin.com/datobawuca/edit?html,css,js,output